# Add class to added class from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Had this:

```
 $(function(){
        $("a.next.down").click(function() {
            $("ul.panel li").addClass("upOne");
            $("a.next").removeClass("down").addClass("downTwo");
        });
        $("a.next.downTwo").click(function() {
            $("ul.panel li").addClass("upTwo");
            $("a.next").removeClass("downTwo").addClass("downThree");
        });
    });
```

And wondering when I click the second event `a.next.downTwo` it doesn't remove the class and add the new one.

So really is there a way to add and remove classes on each click. So click1(add class A), click2(add class B), etc.

Comment: Do you know about $("#element").removeClass("className").addClass("claasName");

Comment: Did you look at the pastebin? I used .removeClass and .addClass, but the second call doesn't respond.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan I seriously was struggling with the <pre> on the OP it kept returning with an error..

Comment: Just highlight the code and click {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first reaction is: http://pastebin.com/LNjLzrwh.

```
$(function(){
    var panelLi = $("ul.panel li");

    $("a.next").click(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (self.hasClass("down")) {
            panelLi.addClass("upOne");
            self.removeClass("down").addClass("downTwo");
        } else if (self.hasClass("downTwo")) {
            panelLi.addClass("upTwo");
            self.removeClass("downTwo").addClass("downThree");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And that seems to work. After all this learning of JQuery, and reading I forgot the whole "if" and "self".

Comment: Please do not communicate via pastebin. I have copied your code into your answer